# Checking equal digits of numbers between lists?

Tags: prolog, clpfd

***What would be an efficient way to check how many equal ending digits have numbers between lists in prolog?***

For example we have `Lista = [4432,2345,3243]` and `Listb = [3345,3232]`.

In these two lists we have **4432** and **3232** which have ***2 same ending digits*** and **3345 , 2345** which have ***3 same ending digits***. 3243 , 3232 have the same 2 starting digits but I don't count this as valid. I have solved this problem in the slowest way , by checking each number of `Lista` with each number of `Listb`, but this is **very** slow. How can I solve this problem more efficiently?

---

**Edit 1**: I applied some changes to the answer code I managed to find the same digits and the subtree remaining , however I cannot combine them in order to find exactly the numbers that the element of the one list has the same digits with them. Can you help me proceed?

```prolog
same_ending(Tree, N /*4904*/, N-Len-Last) :-
  atom_chars(N, Digs),
  reverse(Digs, RDigs),
  same_ending1(RDigs, Tree, [], Fin, 0, Lens),
  pow2(Lens, Res1),
  Res is Res1-1,
  Len = Res,
  Last = Fin.

same_ending1([], _, Curr, Fin, Len, Len).
same_ending1([Dig|Digs], Tree, Curr, Fin, Len, Len2) :-
  ( select(Dig-SubTree, Tree, _) ->
    ( succ(Len, Len1), append([Dig], Curr, Currn),
      same_ending1(Digs, SubTree, Currn, Fin, Len1, Len2) ) 
    ; 
    Len2 = Len,
    Fin = Curr-Tree
  ).
```

---

**Edit 2**: For the final suggestion on @gusbro 's answer I created this code

```prolog
ssame_endings(L1,[],Curr,Final):- Final=Curr.

ssame_endings(L1, L2,Curr,Final):-
  build_tree(L1, Tree),
  head(L2,H),
  tail(L2,T),  
  findall(Res,same_ending(Tree,H,Res) , Endings),
  append(Curr,Endings,Curr1),
  ssame_endings(L1,T,Curr1,Final).

head([A|_],A).
tail([_|A],A).

pow2(X,Z) :- Z is 2**X.

same_ending(Tree,N, N-Len/LItems):-
  atom_chars(N, Digs),
  reverse(Digs, RDigs),
  same_ending1(RDigs, Tree, 0, Len, SubTree),
  length(SDigs, Len),
  append(SDigs, _, RDigs),
  reverse(SDigs, RSDigs),
  same_ending2(SubTree, RSDigs, [], LItems).

same_ending1([], SubTree, Len, Len, SubTree1):-
  SubTree=[] -> SubTree1=[[]]; SubTree1=SubTree.
same_ending1([Dig|Digs], Tree, Len, Len2, SubTree):-
  (select(Dig-DigSubTree, Tree,Third) ->
    (succ(Len, Len1), same_ending1(Digs, DigSubTree, Len1, Len2, SubTree),same_ending1(Digs,Third,Len1,Len2,SubTree)) ;
    Len2-SubTree=Len-Tree
  ).
```

I used *findall* as suggested in order to combine all the answers given and I think that part is correct as I have written it. Then I used *select* after  that which as I understand if we have the tree [1-[2-[3,4]] and we want both 1,2,3 and 1,2,4. if we have the number 5321 the third parameter will also give us 124. However the way I am using it does not produce the expected outcome. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a tree of reversed digits for the first list, then traverse the tree for each reversed item in the second list. This may be more efficient if the list have many items.

```
same_endings(L1, L2, Endings):-
  build_tree(L1, Tree),
  maplist(same_ending(Tree), L2, Endings).

same_ending(Tree, N, N-Len):-
  atom_chars(N, Digs),
  reverse(Digs, RDigs),
  same_ending1(RDigs, Tree, 0, Len).

same_ending1([], _, Len, Len).
same_ending1([Dig|Digs], Tree, Len, Len2):-
  (select(Dig-SubTree, Tree, _) ->
    (
        succ(Len, Len1), 
        same_ending1(Digs, SubTree, Len1, Len2)
    ) ;
    Len2=Len
  ).

build_tree(L, Tree):-
  foldl(add_tree, L, [], Tree).

add_tree(N, Tree, NTree):-
  atom_chars(N, Digs),
  reverse(Digs, RDigs),
  add_tree1(RDigs, Tree, NTree).

add_tree1([], Tree, Tree).
add_tree1([Dig|Digs], Tree, [Dig-SubTree1|Tree1]):-
  (select(Dig-SubTree, Tree, Tree1) -> true; SubTree-Tree1=[]-Tree),
  add_tree1(Digs, SubTree, SubTree1).
```

Test sample:

```
?- same_endings( [4432,2345,3243] , [3345,3232], Endings).
Endings = [3345-3, 3232-2].
```

You may modify this code a bit to obtain the actual items which have the same endings.

---

With a slight modification of the code above you can also list the actual numbers from the first list that have the same (maximum) ending on each item from the second list:

```
same_endings(L1, L2, Endings):-
  build_tree(L1, Tree),
  maplist(same_ending(Tree), L2, Endings).

same_ending(Tree, N, N-Len/LItems):-
  atom_chars(N, Digs),
  reverse(Digs, RDigs),
  same_ending1(RDigs, Tree, 0, Len, SubTree),
  length(SDigs, Len),
  append(SDigs, _, RDigs),
  reverse(SDigs, RSDigs),
  same_ending2(SubTree, RSDigs, [], LItems).

same_ending1([], SubTree, Len, Len, SubTree).
same_ending1([Dig|Digs], Tree, Len, Len2, SubTree):-
  (memberchk(Dig-DigSubTree, Tree) ->
    (
        succ(Len, Len1), 
        same_ending1(Digs, DigSubTree, Len1, Len2, SubTree)
    ) ;
    Len2-SubTree=Len-Tree
  ).

same_ending2([], _, LItems, LItems).
same_ending2([Dig-DigSubTree|SubTree], Digs, MItems, LItems):-
  (Dig=endmarker -> 
    (
        number_chars(Item, Digs), 
        NItems=[Item|MItems]
    ) ;
    same_ending2(DigSubTree, [Dig|Digs], MItems, NItems)
  ), 
  same_ending2(SubTree, Digs, NItems, LItems).

build_tree(L, Tree):-
  foldl(add_tree, L, [], Tree).

add_tree(N, Tree, NTree):-
  number_chars(N, Digs),
  reverse(Digs, RDigs),
  add_tree1(RDigs, Tree, NTree).

add_tree1([], Tree, [endmarker-[]|Tree]).
add_tree1([Dig|Digs], Tree, [Dig-SubTree1|Tree1]):-
  (select(Dig-SubTree, Tree, Tree1) -> true; SubTree-Tree1=[]-Tree),
  add_tree1(Digs, SubTree, SubTree1).
```

Test cases:

```
?- same_endings( [4432,2345,3243] , [3345,3232], Endings).
Endings = [3345-3/[2345], 3232-2/[4432]].
?- same_endings( [4432,2345,3243,2195345,2345] , [3345,3232,19232,2195345], Endings).
Endings = [3345-3/[2195345, 2345, 2345], 3232-2/[4432], 19232-2/[4432], 2195345-7/[2195345]].
```

There's no special treatment for the case when an item does not share any ending digit, the code just spits the whole list in that case.

---

If you want to get all the items with at least 1 matching ending digit, just change the procedures `same_endings` and `same_endings1` with these ones:

```
same_endings(L1, L2, Endings):-
  build_tree(L1, Tree),
  findall(Ending, (member(N, L2), same_ending(Tree, N, Ending)), Endings).

same_ending1([], SubTree, Len, Len, SubTree).
same_ending1([Dig|Digs], Tree, Len, Len2, SubTree):-
  (select(Dig-DigSubTree, Tree, RestTree) ->
    ( 
     (
       Len\=0, 
       RestTree \= [], 
       Len2=Len, 
       SubTree=RestTree
     ) ;
     (
       succ(Len, Len1), 
       same_ending1(Digs, DigSubTree, Len1, Len2, SubTree)
     )
    ) ;
    Len2-SubTree=Len-Tree
  ).
```

Comment: I edited the question , because I am truing to obtain the actual items which have the same endings , but I am having a difficutly

Comment: thanks for the edit, what if 3345 has 2 same ending digits with another number , not just 3

Comment: @Vaas: this algorithm shows the numbers with the maximum "same endings". If you want to show other numbers you would change `same_ending1` to add the other numbers

Comment: I have been trying to do this for days , can you give me a hint?

Comment: the problem I am having modifying this code , is that the program "moves on" until there are no more equal digits left on the tree. But I can't find a way to add the numbers that have less equal digits than the max, because if I stop it everytime it finds one more equal digit , we will have many duplicates. For example if the first list was [4432,2345,3243,2195345,2345,9995] then in the result I should have [3345-3/[2195345, 2345, 2345] , 3345-1/[9995],....] , but it seems impossible they way this code was written. Am I wrong?

Comment: @VassA: You can get what you want by changing a couple of lines of the code. In `same_ending1` change `memberchk` for` select` and use the third parameter. Also you wil also probably need to change `maplist` in `same_endings` to use `findall` instead.

Comment: I have updated my question with your suggestions , I think something is going wrong , with select .

Comment: Did you see the changes sir?

Comment: °⊙◉ ... indentation, please

Answer (score 0):

```erlang
shared_tail_len_atom(A,B,N,S) :-
    sub_atom(A,_,N,0,S),
    N>=1, % raise this value to reduce overhead
    sub_atom(B,_,N,0,S).

same_endings_easy(As,Bs,Es) :-
    setof(N-ab(A,B),
          aggregate(
              max(C),
              S^( member(A,As),
                  member(B,Bs),
                  shared_tail_len_atom(A,B,C,S)
              ), N), Es).
```

You can try this simple snippet. sub_atom/5 it's an ISO Prolog builtin, but the fact that it works with numbers could be a SWI-Prolog extension.

```erlang
?- same_endings_easy([123,223,333],[423,433],Endings).
Endings = [1-ab(123, 433), 1-ab(223, 433), 1-ab(333, 423), 2-ab(123, 423), 2-ab(223, 423), 2-ab(333, 433)].
```

Comment: it gets ' how many equal ending digits have numbers between lists', sorted by lengths